# Group think challenge

Tags: word, letters

What missing member/s does each group have?
The first letter sets of related words are as ff:

> S E W (?) $\checkmark$
>
> S W S (?) $\checkmark$
>
> T I M R (?) $\checkmark$
>
> S S T T (?) $\checkmark$
>
> R K K B P (?) $\checkmark$
>
> S T U B C (?) $\checkmark$
>
> D T R S M F (?) $\checkmark$
>
> D D G H S S (?) $\checkmark$
>
> G O B I R Y (?) $\checkmark$
>
> A A A A A A (?) $\checkmark$
>
> J U M M E N N S (?) $\checkmark$
>
> M A D O N S J A M (? ? ?) $\checkmark$
>
> J J A F F S S E N T T T (? ?) $\checkmark$

Comment: Is there a meaning behind the rearrangement of the letters, or is it just a way to obfuscate the answer?

Comment: tried to give meaning but rather simply defocusing

Comment: Interesting puzzle! I was hoping the discovered letters would anagram into a word or phrase, though.

Comment: Echoing @IanMacDonald, I think this puzzle would have been better if the letters were given in a sensible order.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

S E W (?) $\checkmark$ [Rubio](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30633/rubio)

> S E W (?) → **S**outh **E**ast **W**est **N**orth, therefore (**N**)?

S W S (?) $\checkmark$ [JonMark Perry](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11497/jonmark-perry)

> Spring, Winter, Summer, **A**utumn

T I M R (?) $\checkmark$ [mnemonic](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/27014/mnemonic)

> Thumb, Index, Middle, Ring, **P**inky

S S T T (?) $\checkmark$ [ffao](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/20521/ffao)

> Smell, Sight, Touch, Taste, **H**earing

R K K B P (?) $\checkmark$ [ffao](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/20521/ffao)

> Rook, King, Knight, Bishop, Pawn, **Q**ueen

S T U B C (?) $\checkmark$ [Kevin Long](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30620/kevin-long)

> **S**trange **T**op **U**p **B**ottom **C**harm **D**own (types of [quarks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark))

D T R S M F (?) $\checkmark$ [Kevin Long](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30620/kevin-long)

> **D**o **T**i **R**e **S**o **M**i **F**a **L**a

D D G H S S (?) $\checkmark$ [indubitablee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/35972/indubitablee)

> Doc, Dopey, Grumpy, Happy, Sleepy, Sneezy, **B**ashful

G O B I R Y (?) $\checkmark$ [Silenus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/31484/silenus)

> **R**ed **O**range **Y**ellow **G**reen **B**lue **I**ndigo **V**iolet. So the missing letter is **V**.

A A A A A A (?) $\checkmark$ [indubitablee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/35972/indubitablee)

> Asia, (North) America, (South) America, Africa, Australia, Antarctica, **E**urope

J U M M E N N S (?) $\checkmark$ [JonMark Perry](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11497/jonmark-perry)

> Jupiter, Uranus, Mercury, Mars, Earth, Neptune, Nine, Saturn, **V**enus

M A D O N S J A M (? ? ?) $\checkmark$ [Ian MacDonald](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/10399/ian-macdonald)

> March April December October November September January August May **July February June**

J J A F F S S E N T T T (? ?) $\checkmark$ [ffao](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/20521/ffao)

> Joker, Jack, Ace, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Two, Three, **Q**ueen, **K**ing

Answer (score 8):

J U M M E N N S (?)

> Jupiter, Uranus, Mercury, Mars, Earth, Neptune, Nine, Saturn, **V**enus

S W S (?)

> Spring, Winter, Summer, **A**utumn

Comment: Nine? Did you mix up your mnemonic device with the answer, or is there some astronomical development I'm behind on hearing about?

Comment: @feelinferrety [Planet Nine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_Nine) has replaced our beloved pluto

Answer (score 8):

S S T T (?)

> Smell, Sight, Touch, Taste, **H**earing

J J A F F S S E N T T T (? ?)

> Joker, Jack, Ace, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Two, Three, **Q**ueen, **K**ing

R K K B P (?)

> Rook, King, Knight, Bishop, Pawn, **Q**ueen

Comment: I ought to check mark the summary of all that have contributed to the completion of the puzzle..just recognizing  ffao for best effort..

Answer (score 8):

T I M R (?)

> **T**humb, **I**ndex, **M**iddle, **R**ing, **P**inky

Answer (score 7):

Am I understanding this correctly?
The letters given are

> the first letters of a set of associated words, e.g.
>  S E W (?) → **S**outh **E**ast **W**est **N**orth, therefore (**N**)?

Comment: Yes N is correct

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if these are supposed to be ordered or if they're supposed to mean something over and above the simple letters shown, but this one is:

M A D O N S J A M (? ? ?)

> M(arch) A(pril) D(ecember) O(ctober) N(ovember) S(eptember) J(anuary) A(ugust) M(ay) **J(uly) F(ebruary) J(une)**

Answer (score 7):

G O B I R Y (?)

is

> **R**ed **O**range **Y**ellow **G**reen **B**lue **I**ndigo **V**iolet. So the missing letter is **V**.

Comment: all are English words..not sure if that set is international

Answer (score 7):

D D G H S S (?)

> Doc, Dopey, Grumpy, Happy, Sleepy, Sneezy, **B**ashful

A A A A A A (?)

> Asia, (North) America, (South) America, Africa, Australia, Antarctica, **E**urope

Answer (score 7):

S T U B C (?)

> **S**trange **T**op **U**p **B**ottom **C**harm **D**own (types of [quarks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark))

D T R S M F (?)

> **D**o **T**i **R**e **S**o **M**i **F**a **L**a

Comment: What is this from?

Comment: @leigero There's a hyperlink in the answer.

Comment: +1 for the dtrsmf. not sure about the stubc though

Answer (score -1):

S E W (?)

> N - South East West North

Comment: This answer is already given. Also, you need to put the spoiler blocks using '>!' before your content. Welcome to PSE! Hope you already took a [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour)